# Routing in AngularJS with variable in the beginning of the URL

Tags: rest, web-applications, angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I'm experiencing some behavior that I can't explain, but I'm sure somebody else can. I'm setting up my app module like so:

```
var appmodule = angular.module('appmodule', ['ui']).config(
['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', 
        controller: dashCtr,
        layer: 'main'
      }).
      when('/:campaignId/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html',
        controller: campaignCtr,
        layer: 'layer1'
      }).
      when('/:campaignId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/campaign_info.html',
        controller: campaignCtr,
        layer: 'layer1'
      }).
      when('/inbox', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/inbox.html',
        controller: inboxCtr,
        layer: 'main'
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
}]);
```

When I navigate to app.com/:campaignId or app.com/:campaignId/edit, all works as expected, but if I try app.com/inbox (or anything else), I get redirected back to /dashboard. I've read in a few other places a URL can't begin with a variable, but I'm new to this concept (usually just to design side of the front-end) and don't understand why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is simply because `inbox` route is below ''/:campaignId' route. Angular checks rules in the order they were defined, and ''/:campaignId' rule is matching every single url, so there is no chance to get to 'inbox' route.

Just define '/:campaign' routes after all other routes and everything should be working.

Comment: Ah, cool. Your solution worked, but I also changed the routing to /campaign/:campaignId which lets it work no matter where it was defined.